# How to display inline image in Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have tried `M-x org-toggle-limage-in-org, org-display-inline-images,iimage-mode`. However, all these cannot display my images. See attached screen shot. 
I have added the 
`(autoload 'iimage-mode "iimage" "Support Inline image minor mode." t)
(autoload 'turn-on-iimage-mode "iimage" "Turn on Inline image minor mode." t)`
in my `init.el`.

Maybe because Emacs needs something to show the images?

[[image: screenshot[1]]

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I don't know if bmp is supported.  Can you view a png?  What OS and what version of Emacs?  Try evaluating `(image-type-available-p 'png)` and the same thing for bmp.

Comment: Are you sure that your version of emacs was compiled with image support? Not necessarily true on Windows, and needs image magick on linux for some things.